# Bluetooth: How to connect two servers to one clients

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm looking for a solution to connect several Bluetooth microphones to one android device. Bluetooth transmitter and splitter might be a solution, but is there any easier approach? Thanks!

Comment: What are the servers?

Comment: the servers are microphones with Bluetooth adapter，like samsung level headphone...

Comment: A server cannot connect with a client. It's the client who connects with a server. So please reword your post as now it does not make sense.